# Get the AppleCoreMedia user agent string value on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, user-agent

I noticed that when playing video on my iPhone app, the MediaPlayer sent User-Agent: AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.9A334 (iPhone Simulator; U; CPU OS 5_0 like Mac OS X; en_us)
to server
Is that any way to get the User Agent string value "AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.9A334 (iPhone Simulator; U; CPU OS 5_0 like Mac OS X; en_us)" just using official API ?

Comment: did u get the Solution?